Missing Media Drivers when installing windows 10
I am using Ubuntu as my main Os right now, but I want to install Windows 10 again because I can't do much on Ubuntu right now. The issue is when the Setup Tries load it says missing media drivers and you can't bypass it, so i need help to find the Driver.

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   You can use ubuntu-drivers autoinstall to add drivers automatically on Ubuntu, but you appear to be asking about windows, and windows is not Ubuntu

If you're asking about windows; don't forget there are many forms of install media for windows... You'll be best using the OEM driver provided by your machine maker, as it'll have all you need, as those provided/downloaded by Microsoft only contain a bare set of drivers without those added by the OEMs later in the process. Either way you're off-topic here, as this isn't a windows/microsoft support site.  If you want Ubuntu support; you'll need to be specific with Ubuntu product/release details & what you need a linux kernel module (driver) for.
